# Como juntar dois arrays no angular

Tags: angular

Eu tenho uma service me retornando um array que contem fotos e quando eu "scrollo" pagina ele soma +1 na pagina de fotos e eu queria mostrar as novas fotos abaixo das fotos atuais

```
  getPhotos(page: number) {
    this.updateMasonryLayout = true;
    this.unsplashAPI.random(0 + page)
      .subscribe(
        (photos: any[]) => this.photos = photos,
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = error as any
      );
  }
```

Esse codigo me retorna a pagina mas sempre troca a pagina atual ou seja troca os valores do array e eu quero manter os valores antigos mais os valores novos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o es6 tem a possiblidade de fazer com deconstructing

```
arrNovo = [...arr1, ...arr2] // voce pode fazer com quantos arrays quiser e a ordem importa.
```

Comment: eu teria que criar um array para receber o antigo primeiro? pq eu queria que ficasse somando o retorno no array atual como um +=

Comment: vc pode fazer arrAtual= [...arrAtual, ...arrNovo]

Comment: entao fica this.photos =[...this.photos, ...photos] isso né?

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
getPhotos(page: number) {
    this.updateMasonryLayout = true;
    this.unsplashAPI.random(0 + page)
      .subscribe(
        (photos: any[]) => this.photos = this.photos.concat(photos),
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = error as any
      );
  }
```

Comment: nao funcionou desse jeito apresenta o seguinte erro Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

Comment: O ```this.photos``` deve ser iniciado com um array vazio. Provavelmente ele não está sendo iniciado, com isso chegando ```undefined``` e estourando o erro. ```.concat``` é um método de array.

Comment: ele esta inicializado como array

Comment: Tem como você colocar o código do component e do service pra ter uma ideia melhor do que pode estar acontecendo então?

Comment: Nao tem como são muitas coisas antes disso mas pesquisei sobre o concat e ele nao funciona mais a partir do angular 5

Comment: Tem com disponibilizar o link de onde você pegou essa informação? Pois eu já usei o ```.concat``` em um projeto angular 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092458/merge-two-object-arrays-with-angular-2-and-typescript/46712822

Comment: O concat funciona em qualquer versão do angular. Tudo que você pode fazer com vanila js você consegue fazer com angular

Comment: então eu devo ter ter declaro o this.photos errado mas não vejo onde esta errado, obrigado pela ajuda